# Save a favorite icon when a user logs out or refreshes the page, react, mern stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

Good morning everyone, I have a button component that controls whether or not the user wants to make something a favorite or not. Everything works like it should, as long as I don't log out or refresh the page.

I feel like I know the logic of how to implement this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have the array of favorites saved in local storage, as well as in my database. How would I go about setting the state of the button to be clicked or not on initial render?

here is the code for my button.

```
export default function FavoriteButton({
  _id,
  title,
  artist,
  rating,
  genre,
  description,
}) {
  //state for favorites
  const [click, handleClick] = React.useState(false);

  const [favorite, setFavorite] = React.useState([]);

  //get favorites

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/favorite/get",
      authToken
    );

    setFavorite(result);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  //add favorites
  const addFavorites = () => {
    const favorites = {
      userId: _id,
      title,
      artist,
      rating,
      genre,
      description,
    };

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/favorite/add", favorites, authToken)
      .then((response) => {
        setFavorite(response);
      });

    fetchData();
    localStorage.setItem("favorite", JSON.stringify(favorite));

    handleClick(true);
  };

  // delete favorite

  const deleteFavorite = async () => {
   await axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/favorite/delete", {
      data: { title: title },
      authToken,
    });

    handleClick(false);
  };

  const classes = buttonStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      {click === false ? (
        <IconButton onClick={addFavorites} className={classes.favoriteOff}>
          {" "}
          <StarOutlineIcon className={classes.favoriteGrey} />{" "}
        </IconButton>
      ) : (
        <IconButton onClick={deleteFavorite} className={classes.favoriteOn}>
          {" "}
          <StarRateIcon className={classes.favoriteYellow} />
        </IconButton>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am mapping over data in another component and show the button there.

I have added the parent component here

```
export default function ShowRecords() {
  const classes = recordFormStyles();
  const url = " http://localhost:5000/record";

  //get userData state to use in useEffect

  //set state for showing records in database and opening/closing modals

  const [newRecords, newRecordData] = React.useState([]);

  const [editOpen, handleEditModal] = React.useState(false);

  const [addModalOpen, handleAddModal] = React.useState(false);

  //set state for edit records

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");

  const [artist, setArtist] = React.useState("");

  const [rating, setRating] = React.useState("");

  const [genre, setGenre] = React.useState("");

  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");

  const [userId, setUserId] = React.useState("");

  //set state for favorite icon

  //functions to control state

  const handleAddModalOpen = () => {
    handleAddModal(true);
  };

  const handleCloseAddModal = () => {
    handleAddModal(false);
  };

  const handleIsEditModalClose = () => {
    handleEditModal();
  };

  //fetch record data

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/record/get",
      authToken
    );
    newRecordData(result.data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // delete records

  const deleteRecord = async (_id) => {
    const deleteRecords = {
      _id: _id,
    };

    await axios
      .delete("http://localhost:5000/record/" + _id, deleteRecords)
      .then((result) => {
        const refresh = newRecords.filter((result) => result._id !== _id);
        newRecordData(refresh);
      });
  };

  //functions for controlling edit record state

  const editRecord = (_id, title, artist, rating, genre, description) => {
    setUserId(_id);
    setTitle(title);
    setArtist(artist);
    setRating(rating);
    setGenre(genre);
    setDescription(description);
    handleEditModal(true);

    console.log(title);
  };

  //functions for setting favorite state and color and post request to add favorite

  return (
    <div>
      {/* set props */}

      <Favorites />
      <AddRecord
        isAddModalOpen={addModalOpen}
        handleIsAddModalClose={handleCloseAddModal}
        addNewRecords={newRecords}
        handleIsAddModalOpen={handleAddModal}
        refreshRecordData={newRecordData}
      />
      <EditRecords
        editModalOpen={editOpen}
        handleCloseEditModal={handleIsEditModalClose}
        editUserId={userId}
        editTitle={title}
        editArtist={artist}
        editRating={rating}
        editGenre={genre}
        editDescription={description}
        editTitleState={setTitle}
        editArtistState={setArtist}
        editRatingState={setRating}
        editGenreState={setGenre}
        editDescriptionState={setDescription}
        editUrl={url}
        editFetchData={fetchData}
        editNewRecordData={newRecordData}
      />
      <Button
        className={classes.addButton}
        onClick={() => handleAddModalOpen(true)}
      >
        Add Record
      </Button>

      <div className={classes.cardsContainer}>
        <Grid container spacing={10} style={{ padding: "24px" }}>
          {newRecords.length > 0 &&
            newRecords.map((element) => (
              <Grid key={element._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4} xl={2}>
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                  <CardContent>
                    <>
                      <FavoriteButtonRecord
                        key={element._id}
                        title={element.title}
                        artist={element.artist}
                        rating={element.rating}
                        genre={element.genre}
                        description={element.description}
                      />
                    </>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">
                      {element.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Artist: {element.artist}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Label: {element.rating}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Genre: {element.genre}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Description: {element.description}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>

                  <CardActions>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() =>
                        editRecord(
                          element._id,
                          element.title,
                          element.artist,
                          element.rating,
                          element.genre,
                          element.description
                        )
                      }
                      size="small"
                      color="inherit"
                      className = {classes.button}
                    >
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() =>
                        deleteRecord(
                          element._id,
                          element.title,
                          element.artist,
                          element.rating,
                          element.genre,
                          element.description
                        )
                      }
                      size="small"
                      color="inherit"
                      className = {classes.button}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

let me know if I need to show that code as well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One of the clean solutions could be: pass a prop `isFavorite` to your button component. This prop should tell you whether this button is/was marked favourite or not.    Now the parent component which contains the list of buttons, should call the API to fetch favourite and supply a true or false  in `isFavorite` prop for button, depending upon the value returned from that API for the button-id.

Comment: That sounds totally doable, I was making it way too complicated. So in my useEffect for my parent component I need to fetch the data from my favorites. Assign a state (true), pass that state to my button and then use that prop in my ternary operator?

Comment: on track @wjpayne83

Comment: I supplied my parent component. I guess my only other question is how to set the prop to true only for the buttons found in favorites?? I have only been at this for 3 months.

Comment: I assume, every card is associated with a favorite button.  So let us say we have three  cards with `_id` as `1`,`2`,`3`. Now my API should give me something like `{1:false,2:true}` which means during last activity, `_id:1` was marked `unfavorite` , `_id:2` was marked `favorite` while there is no record for `_id:3`.
So this object should be used to set the `favorite` prop of `<FavoriteButton>` to be `true`, if the above response object has `true` for that `_id`, else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you out here.

Firstly, there is something you should do, don't handle the updates in the Favorite Button Component itself. Pass in the handlers from the parent component that will update the state and use data from the parent components in props.

I will share an example,  this will make things more clear.
We will make a UserList with UserCard Component, including marking the user as favorite or mark as not favorite.

```
export default function UserList() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('/api/users');
    setUsers(result.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  });

  const markUserFavourite = async(userId) => {
    const updatedUser = await axios.post('/api/user/favourite', {userId});
    const otherUsers = users.filter(elem => elem._id !== userId);
    setUsers([...otherUsers, updatedUser]);
  };

  const removeUserFavourite = async(userId) => {
    const updatedUser = await axios.post('/api/user/favourite/remove', {userId});
    const otherUsers = users.filter(elem => elem._id !== userId);
    setUsers([...otherUsers, updatedUser]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map(user => (
        <UserCard user={user} markFavourite={markUserFavourite} 
          removeFavourite={removeUserFavourite} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And, Here is the UserCard, which shows the user details only

```
export default function UserCard(props) {
  const {user, markFavourite, removeFavourite} = props;
  const {name, _id, email, isFavorite} = user;
  return (
    <div>
      Name: {name}
      Email: {email}
      {isFavorite? 
        <button type="button" onClick={removeFavourite(_id)}> Remove Favorite </button> :
        <button type="button" onClick={markFavourite(_id)}> Mark Favorite </button>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

hope, my answer helps your case.

Comment: That definitely makes things more clear! I will try to implement this when I get a chance and let you know how it works out. I have all the logic there, just not using them in the right place

Comment: I am a little confused on something here, where is isFavorite coming rom?

Comment: the isFavorite is stored in the database along with other details of user.

Comment: Duh. I have to refactor A LOT of code to implement this, but it's definitely clear now. I added the favorite button as a last minute add on. Silly me for not making components smaller. I will accept the answer because the logic seems sound and I can from here!